# retrieving and restoring textview information from sharedpreferences

Tags: android, textview, sharedpreferences, restore

I have an activity that allows user to enter notes and store them in dynamically created  textviews. However, when the use leaves the activity and returns, all the created textviews disappear. How can i store store or retrieve all of these created textviews, whenever i return to the activity? Also, i think that my sharedpreferences will be overwriting each time a new textview is added. Any suggestions?

```
public class DocNoteActivity extends Activity {
private LinearLayout nLayout;
private EditText etDocNote;
private Button btnAdd1;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.adddocnote);           
    etDocNote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDocNote);
    btnAdd1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd1);
    nLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    TextView tvNote = new TextView(this);
    tvNote.setText("");         
    btnAdd1.setOnClickListener(onClick());
}

private OnClickListener onClick() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String newDocNote = etDocNote.getText().toString();
            nLayout.addView(createNewTextView(newDocNote));
            getSharedPreferences("myprefs", 0).edit().putString("etDocNote", newDocNote).commit();
        }

    };
}
private TextView createNewTextView(String newText) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TextView tvNote = new TextView(this);
    tvNote.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    tvNote.setText(newText);

    return tvNote;
}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you try to save them in the SQLite DB?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the Notes you have to use the Database (i.e. SQLite) because every time you save the notes in SharedPreferences it will be override. So I recommend you to use the Database. For that here are some useful resources which i think help you.

1 - http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

2 - http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

3 - http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/06/simple-example-using-androids-sqlite_02.html

**NOTE - SharedPreferences are used to store key-value pair data. Mostly it is we can say one kind of Session Management in Android way. I mostly store username & password kind of data in SharedPreferences.**

Hope this helps.